# Authorization has been denied for this request in AAD

Tags: c#, cordova, azure, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Azure Active Directory development. We have few services which need to be accessed by web application and mobile devices(cordova based application).

- For Web application we are using [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).
- For mobile application we are using [Azure AD with an Apache Cordova
  app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-cordova/).

### Issue

The token generating with ADAL JS is authorizing over the web services and working as expected. But the token generating with Azure AD is throwing respective error

> Authorization has been denied for this request

### Workaround

We tried to get access token using user credentials in C#. We are successful in achieving it. Using that access token we tried to hit our services in Fiddler. Even then the same error was thrown.

> Authorization has been denied for this request

### Code Samples

Cordova Code

```
    var authority = 'https://login.windows.net/**tenantName**';
var resourceUrl = 'https://graph.windows.net/';
var clientID = '***CLIENT ID IN NATIVE APP***';
var redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:49906/';
var tenantName = '***TENANT NAME***';
var endpointUrl = resourceUrl + tenantName;

createContext: function () {
            AuthenticationContext.createAsync(authority)
            .then(function (context) {
                mapp.authContext = context;
                mapp.log("Created authentication context for authority URL: " + context.authority);
                mapp.acquireToken();
            }, mapp.error);
        },
        acquireToken: function () {
            if (mapp.authContext == null) {
                mapp.error('Authentication context isn\'t created yet. Create context first');
                return;
            }
            mapp.authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUrl, clientID).then(function (success) {
                console.log("INSIDESILENT");
                mapp.error("Failed to acquire token: " + success);
                console.log("DATA:::: "+success);
            }, function () {
                mapp.authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientID, redirectUrl)
                .then(function (authResult) {
                    mapp.log('Acquired token successfully: ' + pre(authResult));
                    console.log("DATA:::"+authResult.accessToken);
                    localStorage.setItem("SSOFlag", "true");
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['keurapp']);
                    userDetail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails"));
                }, function (err) {
                    mapp.error("Failed to acquire token: " + pre(err));
                });
            });
        }
```

C# Code

```
public static string GetAccessToken()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/**tenantName**", true);
            UserCredential clientCred = new UserCredential("***USERID***", "***PASSWORD***");
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "***APP ID URI OF WEB APPLICATION***", clientId: "***CLIENT ID NATIVE APP***", userCredential: clientCred);
            token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
```

Services Samples:

```
//[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
//[Authorize]
public class RepositoryController : ApiController
{
    //With Few methods
}

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureOAuth(app);
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Looking out for help

Comment: What are the nuget packages and version you are using for AAD, Graph API etc?

Comment: @juvchan These nuget package versions we are using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory V2.19, Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient V2.1.0